# Is it common for hotels to allow requests when booking a room?

Tags: usa, bookings, hotels

I looked around a bit for this question and didn't see it anywhere, but it's something I've never known.

A few friends and I are taking a trip soon, and I was wondering if it is common for hotels to offer an option for special requests when you book a room online. For example, if someone wanted to request a room away from anything noisy, like a wall next to a busy road or vending machines, would that be something to expect when booking?

Comment: You can certainly ask, but I doubt any hotel will promise it...

Comment: Depending where you're booking, some (online) places do have such a request/comment box before you confirm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Requesting specific criteria for your booked room is indeed a service provided professional travel agents. My employer's corporate travel agency ([Carlson Wagonlit](http://carlsonwagonlit.co.uk/)) for instance provide a common selection of special requests as shown the in the picture below. Choosing one of these only indicates a preference, not a guarantee, since it's highly dependent on the yield management system / occupancy at the hotel. (There may be specific exemptions on whether it's binding, usually for persons with physical disabilities for instance, who may need an accessible room.)

[image: Hotel booking special requests]

Providing this kind of choice is considerably less common with many consumer online booking tools. However, in most cases you can phone / contact the hotel following the booking and make the request.

Having higher tier status on a hotel chain loyalty programme - if it belongs to one - may also help your chances of having your request fulfilled.

That said, I've mostly found that hotel checkin staff *will* try to ensure your request is met. Reminding them of it helps.

Comment: Personally, when I request a special room (smoking room usually) and it is unavailable, I ask the staff to transfer me when they find one. Usually they will call me next day and inform me my request is available and I transfer.